# Formalization of the concept of a topological charge

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I want to write precisely in mathematical terms what a topological charge is.

This is what I have, but I am not sure of how correct it is. Let $M$ be spacetime. Quantization of $M$ in some QFT will produce a Hilbert space $H_M$ with states $|\psi\rangle$ and observables $\hat{O}$.

Let $h$ be a homoemorphism such that $h(M)=M'$ deforms spacetime. Then a topological charge is an observable that is invariant under such a deformation. That is
$$\hat O|\psi\rangle_{H_M} = \hat O|\psi\rangle_{H_{M'}} $$
**Is this wording/notation precise and accurate? If not can you suggest a better definition. I am trying to point out what is different between Yang-Mills and Chern-Simons and what it means to have a TQFT**

Also I am not sure if I am mixing things up here. I understand that conceptually a topological charge is some quantum number that does not depend on the geometry of the worldline of the particle, but only on the topology of such worldline.